# jQuery mobile swipe to move divs on same screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to use jQuery swipe to move objects on mobile screen. Suppose I have five Boxes 
(div's) on a page. I want user to be able to move those divs on the same screen left/right/up/down wherever the empty space is.

Here in image I have these `divs` elements show as wooden block. What I want is to use jQuery mobile swipe function to move these `divs`.

How is it possible to do that?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried touchSwipe plugin
[touchSwipe](http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/)

Comment: I am trying touchSwipe now .... will let you know with results